# Rollback temporary DB Changes in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2012

I have this problem which seems simple, but have been searching over the internet and couldn't find solution.

Problem/Requirement :
In my c# method,

1. I want to begin a transaction
2. Call some business logic which updates DB eventually with complex logic.(written by someone else)
3. check updated data in database.
4. rollback changes done in step2 unconditionally/forcefully.(even if changes are committed inside business logic)

I tried using `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`, but it is not able to rollback changes forcefully on demand. (changes are not rolled back upon calling `.Dispose`)

Comment: call `Dispose` on transaction scope?

Comment: `I tried using` maybe you should ask how to fix the mistake that you made when using that class? Clearly, TransactionScope is capable of rolling back something if used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If a transaction is commited, it's committed. There is no rolling back afterwards. That's the point of the commit. You will have to change the foreign code eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If "some business logic" is not your own DB call (i.e. some method in connected library) then you cannot rollback changes (if developer of that logic does not provide such possibility).

But if that logic is just some DB call, then you can just rollback your transaction without commit.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    // Start a local transaction.
    SqlTransaction sqlTran = connection.BeginTransaction();

    // Enlist a command in the current transaction.
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = sqlTran;

    try
    {
        // Here is your "business logic"
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbBusinessLogic VALUES(1)";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Check result
        command.CommandText = "Select 1 from tbBusinessLogic";
        var result = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
        CheckResult(result);

        // Rollback the transaction.
        sqlTran.Rollback();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex);
        sqlTran.Rollback();
    }
}
```